# Travels of Prophet Saw before his Prophethood?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, seerah

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

How many times did the Prophet Saw travel outside of Makkah before his prophethood and where to?

Comment: I wonder if the quantity was mentioned, but it is well known that he traveled to Shaam with his Uncle.